# Stream PDF from file system to browser in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Unable to read PDF file from the file system and display it in the browser. Below is a sample of the page_load:

```
        Dim filepath As String = "pdf" <-- this is the actual path to the PDF file on the file system.
        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
        Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
        Dim bytecount As Long
        fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filepath)

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

        While bytecount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

        End While
```

When loading the page, it tries to open the PDF but says PDF is unreadable. Permissions is not an issue, the folder and file has read access to everyone. Any ideas?

Comment: What is Response?  Is this the the producer of the PDF or is this the consumer?  I'm not sure anything can display a stream without some processing to write that stream out to a file and then read the file.

Comment: Response is an object in .Net to send output to browser.

Comment: You may need to look into Response.Clear and Response.Flush as well as what's been suggested thus far... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.flush?view=netframework-4.8 C# example, but it's the same idea...call clear before you write everything out, and flush after you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be the root of your problem but the line inside the loop is wrong. When you read the last block from the file, it may not fill the entire buffer but you are writing the entire buffer anyway. This:

```vb
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

should be this:

```vb
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytecount)
```

Actually, looking more closely, I see that your loop termination condition is wrong too. You've written it like you would in C#, where assignments produce a result. That's not the case in VB, so you have to structure the code a little differently. Considering that, the change mentioned above and some other clean-up, your code should look more like the following:

```vb
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Const BUFFER_LENGTH As Integer = 1024

Dim filePath = "file path here"
Dim buffer(BUFFER_LENGTH - 1) As Byte

Using fs = File.OpenRead(filePath)
    Dim byteCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)

    While byteCount > 0
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
        byteCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)
    End While
End Using
```

That's untested so I'm not sure if there are further issues but that addresses a lot of what's wrong with your existing code.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much. I used C# code as an example but I don't know C# very well so I tried my best to convert to VB. Again, thanks.

Comment: VB and C# are generally very similar but there are some subtle differences, which is why you need to not just translate code directly but, rather, interpret it. If you had read that `While` statement and asked yourself what it was doing, it should have been obvious that it was nothing useful. Copying and pasting someone else's code without understanding what it's doing is never a good idea. The first step should have been to understand the C# code.